# Organic Brønsted base that is not a Lewis base

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Which non-nucleophilic organic bases get protonated by typical Brønsted acids (like $\ce{HCl}$, $\ce{H2SO4}$) but also don't form Lewis acid–base complexes with typical Lewis acids like $\ce{BCl3}$, $\ce{AlCl3}$, $\ce{ZnCl2}$?

Comment: I guess you ask about non-nucleophilic bases.

Comment: I am specifically not asking about non nucleophilic bases, since most of them form Lewis acid base complexes with typical Lewis acids. But of course all bases that do not form  Lewis-acid-base-complexes with typical Lewis Bases should be also non nucleophilic.

Comment: Better rethink that. Steric effects are like only thing that can create such effect. For example for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,6-Di-tert-butylpyridine

Comment: That is already very helpful. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Meeting the condition you set is *likely **imposssible***.

There are multiple approaches how to define an acid, and a base.  Despite differences between them, there are some which are related to each other.  For Brønsted and Lowry, a base is capable to attract and bind a proton; this already is an extension (mathematically speaking, [a *superset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset)) of Arrhenius' focus on aqueous solutions.  But how do you do establish bond toward a proton? By extending a previously not engaged pair of electrons toward $\ce{H+}$; and this is the criterion of a base in Lewis' theory.

If you like a visual approach with [Euler/Venn diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram), than have a look at this illustration:

[image]

(image credit to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction)).

And Lewis acids may, but needn't be an acid according to Brønsted and Lowry (e.g., $\ce{AlCl3}$).